# GWT Compiling without maven throws a compiler error NotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, compilation

so I'm having trouble compiling my application when I'm not using my maven implementation. It will compile without any troubles with the maven-gwt-plugin.

The error I receive says that the generator can't fond the class information it is requesting:

```
Rebinding nz.co.doltech.wayhome.client.core.ReflectionBundle
Invoking generator fr.lteconsulting.hexa.classinfo.gwt.rebind.ClazzBundleGenerator
[ERROR] ERROR when generating null for nz.co.doltech.wayhome.client.core.ReflectionBundle
com.google.gwt.core.ext.typeinfo.NotFoundException: nz.co.doltech.wayhome.client.widgets.SettingForm
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.typemodel.TypeOracle.getType(TypeOracle.java:623)
at com.google.gwt.dev.javac.typemodel.TypeOracle.getType(TypeOracle.java:68)
at fr.lteconsulting.hexa.classinfo.gwt.rebind.ClazzBundleGenerator.generate(ClazzBundleGenerator.java:71)
at com.google.gwt.core.ext.IncrementalGenerator.generateNonIncrementally(IncrementalGenerator.java:40)
```

Obviously that class exists and works in the maven implementation. I can't figure out why its not working when I just do a standard build using the eclipse 'Java Application' run configuration. Here is the setup of my run configuration:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Anyone have any ideas what is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Try right clicking on your project and go to Google -> GWT Compile.

Edit: the above option may not be available to you if you do not have the GWT plugin for Eclipse installed. For more information:

https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/WorkingWithMaven